# Django invalid form due to CharField and its Select widget

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have a Django form that refused to validate because of this Select widget, I have tried to debug and found out that the particular form field has been returning None instead of 'Buy' or 'Sell'. I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with my code, albeit I suspect it has something to do with my HTML.

models.py

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
buy = 'BUY'
sell = 'SELL'
transaction_choices = [
    (buy, 'Buy'),
    (sell, 'Sell'),
]

transaction_type = models.CharField(
    max_length=4,
    choices=transaction_choices,
    default=buy,
)
```

forms.py

```
class UpdatePortfolio(forms.ModelForm):
transaction_choices = [
    ('BUY', 'Buy'),
    ('SELL', 'Sell'),
]

transaction_type = forms.CharField(
    max_length=4,
    widget=forms.Select(
        choices=transaction_choices,
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-select',
            'name': 'transaction_type',
            'id': 'floatingTransaction',
        })
)

 class Meta:
    model = Transaction
    fields = (
        'transaction_date',
        'symbol',
        'transaction_date',
        'share',
        'avg_price',
        'cost_basis',
    )

def clean_transaction_type(self):
    type = self.cleaned_data.get('transaction_type')
    if type != 'Buy' or 'Sell':
        raise forms.ValidationError(f'{type} is an invalid transaction')
    return type
```

updateportfolio.html

```
<form action="{% url 'mainpage:update' user.id %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="row1">
            <div class="transaction_type col-6">
                <p>Transaction Type</p>
                <select class="form-select" required>
                    {% for type in form.transaction_type %}
                        <option>{{ type }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="symbol col-6">
                <label for="floatingSymbol" class="form-label">Ticker</label>
                {{ form.symbol }}
                <datalist id="tickers">
                    {% for ticker in tickers %}
                        <option value="{{ ticker.tickersymbol }}"></option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </datalist>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

This issue has been resolved by changing the field of 'transaction' and removing the unnecessary widget. My updated codes are as shown below.

*forms.py*

```
class UpdatePortfolio(forms.ModelForm):

transaction_type = [
    ('BUY', 'Buy'),
    ('SELL', 'Sell'),
]

transaction = forms.ChoiceField(
    choices=transaction_type,
)
```

*Template*

```
<select name="transaction" class="form-select">
   {% for value, text in form.transaction.field.choices %}
   <option value="{{ value }}" id="id_transaction_{{ forloop.counter0 }}">{{ text }}</option>
   {% endfor %}</select>
```

*models.py*

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    buy = 'BUY'
    sell = 'SELL'
    transaction_type = [
        (buy, 'Buy'),
        (sell, 'Sell'),
    ]

    transaction = models.CharField(
        max_length=200,
        choices=transaction_type,
        default=buy,
    )
```